# Organizational tree drawing algorithm

Tags: c#, silverlight, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm implementing an organizational tree graph - top to bottom or left to right - in C# and looking for a good algorithm to draw the tree. Any recommendations?

Thanks

**Update**

I finally had some time to work on it so ended up writing my own library to store and draw the tree by creating a custom panel, not sure if I followed a particular algorithm, I just wrote my own - back to pen and paper + time :)

I intend to make it open source on codeplex once I'm done adding all the features I wanted. Will post another update once it's up on codeplex.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the keyword you're looking for is [Force-based algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_%28graph_drawing%29).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Also possible if you use just standart Silverlight.
Use an ItemsControl (which has as ContainerTemplate a StackPanel, so you can display the items the vertically or horizontally) in combination with HierarchicalDataTemplate.
The way to display the items you set with ItemTemplate and it should work directly

Answer (score 1):

A cool visualization you can use instead of drawing the tree is a Squarified Treemap.  It's a view of a hierarchical data structure that shows the leaf nodes' relative sizes when packed into a rectangle.  Because it is drawn recursively, two leaf nodes will be drawn different sizes if they are in different size subtrees of the hierarchy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping

Answer (score 0):

One option you might consider is to simply use the TreeView control and transforms to make it appear the way you want it to.

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/149065/334501.aspx

Honestly, I think using a third-party component would be a much better "algorithm" rather than re-inventing.  If you should consider, there are several products that offer this capability for SL:

http://www.nwoods.com/components/silverlight-wpf/goxam-overview.htm
http://www.mindfusion.eu/diagramlite.html
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/silverlight/diagram
http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfilessilverlight_about.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the best article I have found on this subject : [A Graph Tree Drawing Control For wpf](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29518/A-Graph-Tree-Drawing-Control-for-WPF)

It has a WPF and Silverlight version. It implements John Q. Walker II algorithm for positioning nodes and works perfectly. I still have to work on the rotation so it can be displayed left to right. Currently is only top to bottom.

You can find more info on the algorithm here: http://www.cs.unc.edu/techreports/89-034.pdf